# .htaccess Страница по умолчанию

Tags: .htaccess

На сайте, сделал директорию https://www.domain.ru/newdirectory/ внутри index.shtml.
При переходе по ссылке https://www.domain.ru/newdirectory/ пустая страница.
Создал .htaccess в нем написал `DirectoryIndex index.shtml`
Не могу понять в чем проблема.

Comment: Ну как минимум надо в мониторинге сети посмотреть, какой http-статус присылает веб-сервер, и почитать логи этого самого веб-сервера

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать так:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php index.shtml
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .php .shtml
```